# Postfix: modifying email adresses from a ldap query

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, ldap, regex

We query an LDAP for identifying aliases and users on a Postfix server.

Due to company-related reasons, some email adresses have the format "SMTP:user@host.com". To forward mail to this user, we would need to cut off the "SMTP:" in front of it.

One solution could be using regex, but we already use the ldap module and I could not find out how to use both together, e.g. querying an ldap and modify the result by using a regex.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use your regexp in your rewrite rule.
For example:

```
virtual_alias_maps =
    ldap:/etc/postfix/your-ldap-aliases.cf
    regexp:/etc/postfix/myrewrites
```

And set up /etc/postfix/myrewrites :

```
/^SMTP:(.*)$/     ${1}
```

or similar.

Postfix will rewrite your rewritten address just like in /etc/aliases (think about postmaster: root and after that root: admin@mysite.com).